# How to limit User groups name field to three choices?

Tags: django

I have django model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #other fields
```

When I create new UserProfile instance I want have only 3 group names to choice (in admin interface and in my custom form): "student", "instructor", "dean". What is the best way to do it? Should I extend User model or Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have three Group objects created, which correspond to your groups.

Next, you need to limit the choices in the admin. I'm not sure though, I think the group is in the User form? Here is one solution, which is a bit hackish. Override the UserChangeForm from http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py and use it as the custom form in the admin.

```
class UserForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        names = ['student','instructor','dean']
        self.fields['groups'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.filter(name__in=names))

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```